# maximum TextView width in layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a small layout file for the parentView of the ExpandableListView.
If the TextView text is too long it overlays some other views of the layout.

Here is an image: [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnAYW.jpg)

and here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/file_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_line"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_placeholder"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show_file_detail"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/show_file_detail"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_placeholder"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I already google'd the problem but the answers were not so specific.
I tried it with android:layout_toLeftOf the the long text  right aligned and if an short text is shown, it looks aweful.

Does anyone of you guys have an idea?

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="test"
            android:id="@+id/file_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_placeholder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/show_file_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_placeholder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just for my understanding: Why do you put the TextView into a LinearLayout?

Comment: after right side both image place rest of horizontal space taken by textview for display text....